# Are git submodules by default a full copy i.e. not shallow?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I hope this is just a simple yes or no question. I need to create a local backup of my repository. For that I want to clone my repository that includes submodules. So doing:

```bash
git clone <remote> .
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

**If I do this, do I get a fully copy of the repository of the submodules (and nested submodules)?**

I see a lot of question about adding shallow submodules so I'm assuming yes, but I haven't been able to find a statement that the default is a deep copy which I would like to have confirmed.

Extra info:
I read on the git documentation

> The initial clone of a submodule will use the recommended submodule.<name>.shallow as provided by the .gitmodules file by default.

In my .gitmodules I only have the path and url defined.

Comment: Yes. Confirm it using `git rev-parse --show-toplevel --is-shallow-repository` within each submodule. BTW you can use `git clone --recursive` to clone a repo and all of its submodules in a single command.